# Porting Windows IoT Core UWP (C# / XAML) application to Linux

Tags: c#, linux, xaml, uwp, windows-iot-core-10

I have a UWP application with a GUI, written in C# / XAML, currently running on Windows IoT Core. Since there is not a lot of support for Windows IoT Core anymore and updates are rare too, i have to port my application to another platform for the future. 
So when i run Linux (Raspbian) on my IoT devices, which is the best way, to port my current application to it?
Or is it even a good option, to run Android on my IoT devices and port my UWP application with Xamarin?

Answer (score 1):

> Since there is not a lot of support for Windows IoT Core anymore and updates are rare too

This reads like a tabloid article, what exactly are you basing your assumptions on? At a glance, the .Net Core IOT library was last updated 3 days ago: https://github.com/dotnet/iot/commit/d67f974e29918ab3122af3d2d7775110c8d93acb

> which is the best way, to port my current application to it [Raspbian]?

Ironically, using the same IOT library you think isn't maintained anymore. If you're asking about the GUI, you select all of it and delete, then start writing from scratch using your library of choice -- gtk#, Avalonia, Xamarin, whatever you want.

Comment: I don't refer to the .NET Core IoT library, i mean Windows IoT Core in general. The most recent version is still based on 17763. No support for newer (e.g. Raspberry Pi 4) devices. So the general question is, how dead that system is currently. I really love developing for the UWP platform, but when this "project" is no longer maintained, then i have to take a look at alternatives...

Comment: You may post the update reqirement via Feedback Hub App to help Microsoft to improve the experience on Windows Platform.